# Multivariate Multiple Regression with Repeated Measures

Tags: matlab, regression, regression-analysis

I have a dataset with p predictors for i items (so multiple regression). For each of s subjects, I have r repeated observations of v dependent variables (so it's a multivariate problem). I wish to find out for each individual how much variance the p predictors account for across all i items.

The formula for calculating the parameter coefficients (aka betas) (using MATLAB notation) is:

```
Betas=pinv(X'*X)*X'*Y
```

Where X is the [i × p] matrix of predictors, and Y is the matrix of observations. Unfortunately, my Y is a 3D matrix of size [i × r × v]. The matrix multiplication requires a 2D matrix, however I am not sure about which is the correct approach:

1. Concatenate the r observations of v measurements together so that e.g. X=[i × p], Y=[i × (r * v)]
2. Concatenate the r observations of i items together, and replicate the predictor matrix r times so that e.g., X=[(r*i) × p], Y=[(r*i) × v]
3. Average the r observations of v measurements together so that X=[i × p] and Y=[i × v]

The second option multiplies the predictors which seems to be a bad idea, whereas the first option multiplies the dependent variables, which then makes it impossible to use the parameters to predict a set of v values. The last option seems to be the most reasonable, though you lose data through averaging. Are any of these the appropriate course of action?

Comment: Why the second option is a bad idea? It seems for me this is the most natural approach. You prediction $X coef$ will be the same for $r$ repeated observation. So what? But generally replication of $X$, or average of $Y$ over $r$ should give the same answer finally.

Comment: My intuition about the problem with adding extra predictors is that it would artificially increase the number of explanatory variables, thereby inflating the goodness-of-fit.

Comment: This has been crossposted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103700. In the future, please flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate instead of posting a duplicate yourself.

Comment: May be I misunderstood you, but I did not think that  in 2) you multiply the number of predictors (explanatory variables) , you just replicate their length.